# ESLINT: params.majorVersion = m[1]; => Use array destructuring.(prefer-destructuring)

Tags: ecmascript-6, eslint, destructuring

I'm struggling with an Eslint error about this code :

```
const m = version.match(/^(\d+)\.\d+\.\d+/);
...
params.majorVersion = m[1];
```

I have an ESLint error : Use array destructuring.(prefer-destructuring)

I tried different things like

```
const [,majorVersion] = m;
params.majorVersion = majorVersion
```

or

```
const [, majorVersion] = version.match(/^(\d+)\.\d+\.\d+/);
...
params.majorVersion = majorVersion
```

But solution 1 is more verbose, I can't see how destructuring improves anything here. And the 2nd solution doesn't work when there's no match. I'm starting to think there's a problem with this Eslint rule for this code

Am I missing something ?

Comment: I mean, you can configure the rule however you want. https://eslint.org/docs/rules/prefer-destructuring

Comment: It's a useful rule in general, if I wrote something like `const x = m[1]`, I'd like Eslint to tell me something is wrong. The goal of my question was to make sure I didn't miss something before ignoring this error

Comment: You could write `[,params.majorVersion] = m;`. But  I don't think that's any better.

Comment: @FelixKling : it works, thanks a lot ! I agree with you, not sure it's a great improvement though...